# Maven: How to avoid building a module during a release?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I know how to [avoid **deploying** a module during the release process](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/faq.html#skip). What is not clear is how to avoid **building** the module to begin with. For example, my project contains an "examples" module. This takes a very long time to build and is never deployed to Maven Central so I'd like to avoid building it altogether (but only during a deploy). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Maven Release Plugin, you will need to take care of both the *prepare* and the *release* steps, since projects are usually built in both steps.

For the *prepare* step, I would try the `preparationGoals` parameter, which by default uses `clean verify`, which includes a build of the project. Maybe you can try setting it to `clean` only to avoid the build.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html

For the *perform* step, take a look at the `goals` parameter, which by default is set to `deploy`. You can override this by specifying `clean` only.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html

I haven't tried this exact combination, so I don't know whether this will have any side-effects on the rest of the build.

Comment: Your suggestion does not work. The release plugin forks an external process that invokes "mvn clean verify" on the top-level project and this, in turn, processes all sub-modules. In other words, it doesn't look like I can configure different `goals` for `release:prepare` for different modules.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing in this case is to use a profile and put the example into a separate module which can be activated by a profile. This prevents building during release but can be build during usual development etc. via activating profile.

Comment: Yes but this creates two problems: 1. I want `release:prepare` to update the module version numbers but not build it. It's not clear how to do that. 2. Ideally `examples` should build by default (as opposed to making users remember to mention a profile).